# How to add the numbers 1 to 12 using a loop?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
   { 
        int sum = 1;

        while (sum < 12)
        {
            sum = sum + 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

I am new to C# and I have to add the numbers all together. I know adding them up will equal 78 but still don't know how to do it. Any help would be great Thanks!

Comment: Well, here you're not adding 1 + 2 + 3, you're adding 1 + 1 + 1 + 1...

Comment: There's a formula for that - `12(12 + 1) / 2 = 78`

Comment: This question is not clear, perhaps explain why you are trying to sum up to 78

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop that iterates through each number in your set. In your case the set of numbers that is 1-12. Usually a for loop since you know your set ahead of time.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.dotnetperls.com/for

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{  
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 1;

        while (i <= 12)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
            i = i + 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);         
        Console.ReadLine();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   { 
        int sum = 1;
        int totalofSum = 0;
        while (sum <= 12)
        {
            totalofSum = sum + totalofSum;
            sum++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(totalofSum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Where as it would be easier if you use for loop

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    int totalofSum = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
    {
        totalofSum = totalofSum + i;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(totalofSum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Java way...

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
    int i=1,sum=1;
    do{
        sum+=++i;
    }while(i<12);
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}